# How to activate pac-man plug-in in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, pacman

Is there any way to call the pac-man plug-in in Google Maps v3 API?

Thanks!

and happy April fool :p

Comment: just until the end of fools day

Comment: Click the lower left icon ;)

Comment: like, I want to trigger it when a user do something... let say I want to launch the pac-man game automatically if user puts a marker within 100 miles of the google building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a mac you can just press

**CMD + pacman**

in the search field. I however don't know how to this in windows

Comment: he he he he he he he